# do the Zend Studio support the remote javascript debug

Tags: javascript, remote-debugging, zend-studio, phpstorm

I found phpstorm 4 can debug the javascript in remote browser, can the zend studio remote debug the javascript? I know zend studio can remote debug the php, but do it support remote debug javascript also?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not support the remote debugging of javascript.

To log client javascript errors, install Google Analytics and try something like this: http://www.thetaboard.com/blog/client-side-error-logging-with-google-analytics?r=378

Comment: thanks, i search google long times . it should be true the zend studio not support the  javascript remote debug. but i expect it will  support in zend studio  10 .